# How to implement multiselect using Flatlist in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am trying to create a flatlist with text,but it selects only single value but i want to select multiple values from the list.  and i also need color change for selected item. Here i am fetching data from api.
Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";    
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
import {
stepDone,
setInputData,
} from "../../actions";
import Options from "../../components/Options";<----- It is a component Here define the flatlist

class Qualifier extends React.Component {

_afterQualifierSelected = (id, name) => {
const { stepDone, setInputData, input, updateSymptom } = this.props,
  symptomId = input.symptomIds[input.symptomIds.length - 1],
  currentSymptom = input.symptoms.filter(entry => entry.id === symptomId),
  symptom = currentSymptom ? currentSymptom[0] : {};

symptom.qualifier = id;

setInputData("qualifier", { id, name });
stepDone("qualifierSelected");
};

render = () => {
return (
      <Options
         data={this.qualifiers}
         exclusive={true}
         onSelect={this._afterQualifierSelected}
      />
)
}
}
```

options.js

```
 export default class Options extends React.PureComponent {
 static propTypes = {
 data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
 extraData: PropTypes.object,
 exclusive: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
 onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 onDone: PropTypes.func
};

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) =>
   "undefined" === typeof item.id
  ? index.toString()
  : "string" === typeof item.id
  ? item.id
  : item.id.toString();

 _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
const { onSelect } = this.props;
return <Item id={item.id} text={item.name} onPress={onSelect} />;
 };

render = () => {
const { data, extraData, exclusive, onDone } = this.props;
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.listContainer}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        extraData={extraData}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
    </View>
    {!exclusive && (
      <Button
        style={styles.done}
        onPress={onDone}
        title={Language.done}
        accessibilityLabel={Language.optionsDoneAccessibility}
      />
    )}
  </View>
);
};
}
```

How should i implement multi select in this flat list using react native?
Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [multi-select-flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata) example from the official docs. The ListItems are components with their own state & props. You can pass them down whenever your List-component receives a click and do some magic with conditional rendering.

Comment: could you please give me a sample?

Comment: The link contains a full example with ListItem and Flatlist (MultiSelectList). It even changes the color of the ListItem if selected.